# Links and routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.1.1
```

I have an application where I need to display a link to the controller show method. As far as I know, something like this will do it:

```
<%= link_to "Agent", agents_path(:id => agent.id), :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
```

But when Rails generates the link, it's this:

```
http://mydomain/agents?id=9
```

What I need is

```
http://mydomain/agents/9.
```

When I enter this manually, I get the agents/show view. How do I get there?

In my routes, I do not have anything special for agents. Here's the relevant code from routes.rb:

```
resources :agents
```

Which means it will generate all the routes.

rake routes output:

```
agents GET    /agents(.:format)               agents#index
POST   /agents(.:format)                      agents#create
new_agent GET    /agents/new(.:format)        agents#new
edit_agent GET    /agents/:id/edit(.:format)  agents#edit
agent GET    /agents/:id(.:format)            agents#show
PATCH  /agents/:id(.:format)                  agents#update
PUT    /agents/:id(.:format)                  agents#update
DELETE /agents/:id(.:format)                  agents#destroy
```

and I did not get any errors generating the routes

## Solution:

Apologies, but I was using agent_path, not agents_path. I did try agents_path at one point, as one of the things I tried. The problem is that I had two different views. In one, I was using the correct syntax:

```
<%= link_to "Agent", agent_path(agent.id), :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
```

and in the other I was using:

```
<%= link_to "Agent", agents_path(:id => agent.id), :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
```

I kept making changes to one of them, when the other was actually the one being rendered. I put the correct syntax in a partial and now it's working fine. The moral of the story is to always use partials, even when you think you don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routing**

Something you need to consider is the [`resourceful` nature of Rails' routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

[image]

Every time you create a `resources` part of the Rails routing structure, you're actually telling rails to build the above routes. This is standard practice, and means you'll be able to call `article_path(article.id)` as default functionality.

I believe your problem stems from this idea:

```
<%= link_to "Agent", agents_path(:id => agent.id), :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
```

--

**Reference**

As mentioned, you're referencing `agents_path` (plural), when it *should* be `agent_path` (singular).

However, you're also defining the `:id` parameter in the route helper itself. This can just be handled by passing the object itself to the helper:

```
<%= link_to article.title, article_path(article.id) %>
```

Or, more succinctly, Rails is able to determine the path based on the resource you pass it (hence why I mentioned `resourceful` routes structure):

```
<%= link_to article.title, article %>
```

This will you autimagically to the `show` action of the `articles` controller.

Answer (score 4):

You want `agent_path` instead of `agents_path`, and you don't need to specify the `id`. This will work just fine:

```
<%= link_to "Agent", agent_path(agent), :class => "btn btn-warning" %>
```

Whenever in doubt about what the routes are, you can always run:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

And you'll be able to see all existing routes, and their naming.

Comment: I've already tried this and it's still the same. It seems as if no matter what I try for the link, the link's value always comes out the same. I tried changing the name of the button to make sure I'm not hallucinating, and that's changing fine

Comment: `agent_path` (a single resource) and `agents_path` (the resource index) are absolutely not the same. Triple-check your usage and check `rake routes` to confirm you have it right.

Comment: What @ChrisHeald said. If you get an error there, maybe post the output from `bundle exec rake routes`.

Comment: I posted the output of rake routes as an edit. No errors

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper scroll down, you got the correct answer just bellow :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your record to `link_to`, this will automatically generate a link to its view page

```
= link_to 'Agent', agent
<a href="/agents/32">Agent</a>
```

You can do much more by using the record, example if you need a link to the edit page

```
= link_to 'Agent', [:edit, agent]
<a href="/agents/32/edit">Agent</a>
```

And so on... This technique is very useful when writing helpers that must be compatible with different models